# How to exploit with Control over return address and knowing the address of printf

Tags: exploit, aslr

[image]

I have this program that uses ASLR and it leaks information when i overflow a buffer, namely the address of printf. Furthermore i can overwrite the return address. How can i use this to spawn a shell? My approach would have been to calculate the relative offset of system() function with repsect to printf since it is in the same address-space and then overwrite the return address with the address of system(). The problem is that i need to have a "/bin/sh" string as an argument and since the program uses aslr i cant pass this string with environment variables.

How can i exploit this program with knowing the address of printf and overwriting the return adress alone in an ASLR scenario?

Answer (score 1):

The same way you calculate the offset to system within libc, you could also find a string reference to "/bin/sh" in libc and calculate the offset based on the leak. Use `strings -a -t x /path/to/libc.so.6 | grep /bin/sh` to get the offset, then `printf_leak - printf_offset + binsh_offset` to get the memory address.

Or, you may be able to do everything in a single jump since the needed code is usually already in libc. There are tools such as [one_gadget](https://github.com/david942j/one_gadget) out there to automate this.